# Hibernate - Accessing fields from a ManyToMany relation

Tags: hibernate, orm, many-to-many, jpql

I have a ManyToMany table and I want to make a query like this:

**"select e.manytomany.fieldName from Entity e"**

I can't select the ManyToMany table's fields and the only possibility is to select the table (like "select e.manytomany from Entity e") which gives me a Set<>.

is there any way for me to do a query like that?

Comment: What return type do you expect? If you have `@ManyToMany` you have to receive a `Collection`.

Comment: it's returning Set<MyEntity> and because of it being a Collection, I can't use any of its fields just like my example... I also couldn't define a getter method to parse the Set<MyEntity> into an string and use the query like "select e.parsedManyToMany from Entity e"... this solution would also be acceptable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you want to accomplish a join condition.

Classes A & B:

```
public class A {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="a_b", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id")})
    private Set<B> b;

    private String field;
}

public class B {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "b")
    private Set<A> a;
}
```

Query:

```
TypedQuery<String> query = em.createQuery("SELECT a.field FROM A a JOIN B b ON a MEMBER OF b.a AND b = :b", String.class);
query.setParameter("b", someBInstance);
```

that results into a `List<String>`of `"someBInstance.a.field"`

Comment: Thanks... I found the solution last week but your determination to answer still counts...

Comment: Glad you found a solution. thx for my first accepted answer =)